# What does Vector2.scl method do in LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been following a a tutorial recently and really new to game development. There is a method called scl of the Vector2 class in LibGdx. Here is the fragment of my code. My question is. What does it do. If you can do a detailed explanation. Please add some.

```
public void update(float dt){
    if(position.y > 0)
        velocity.add(0, GRAVITY);
    velocity.scl(dt);
    Gdx.app.log("scl dt 1", Float.toString(velocity.y));
    position.add(0, velocity.y, 0);
    if(position.y < 0)
        position.y = 0;
    velocity.scl(1/dt);
}
```

Comment: The javadocs for the methods explain what they do. If you're using Eclipse, you can hover over the method to see the docs. In IDEAS or Android Studio, you can Alt-click the method to see the docs.

Comment: The description was just too complex for me sir. I couldn't understand what does the scale do. Does it multiply or divide or something?

Comment: It simply multiplies the x and y component with the argument you provide to the method. Its source is similar to `Vector2 scl(amount) { this.x *= amount; this.y *= amount; return this; }`

Comment: Reached the heights in game development in 4 years of study?

Answer (score 1):

`scl()` is overloaded method of `Vector2` class.

```
1. public Vector2 scl(float scalar)
```

Scales your vector by a scalar quantity and return.

```
2. public Vector2 scl(float x,float y)
```

Multiplies your vector by a scalar and return itself.

```
3.  public Vector2 scl(Vector2 v)
```

Scales your vector by another vector and return itself.

In above your code you are scaling your vector by dt unit.

**What is dt ?**

dt is the time between the start of the previous and the start of the current call to `render()`. It just takes the current time and subtracts the previous time from it. The unit of this value is seconds.

Comment: I've seen that code somewhere multiple times before--must be from some tutorial. It seems inane to me to scale the velocity into a displacement, add it to the position, and then scale it back to a velocity. It probably also introduces minute error, such that .equals would not work for the velocity any more if comparing it to a constant. It would make more sense to use `position.mulAdd(velocity, dt);`

Comment: I would also recommend position.mulAdd(velocity, dt); instead of scaling and unscaling velocity.

Comment: Sir if the given value of GRAVITY is 15. What would be the value of x and y for the velocity after velocity.scl(dt);

Comment: 15x and 15y. You are simply multiplying all its components by the scalar.